# Labelling error during version comparison

Tags: python, pandas, semantic-versioning

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
api_spec_id   commit_date             info_version          label
500                2020-07-22           1.1 
500                2020-11-09           1.1 
500                2020-11-16           1.1 
500                2020-11-16           1.1 
500                2020-11-23           1.1 
500                2021-02-01           1.1     
138641             2020-06-25          0.1.0                 major
138641             2020-06-25          0.1.0    
138641             2020-06-27          0.1.0    
138641             2020-06-27          0.1.9                 patch
138641             2020-06-27          0.1.10                patch
138641             2020-06-27          0.1.11                patch
138641             2020-06-27          0.1.13                patch
138641             2020-06-27          0.1.14                patch
138641             2020-06-27          0.1.15                patch
138641             2020-06-28          0.2.0                 minor.patch
138641             2020-06-30          0.2.1                 patch
138641             2020-07-01          0.3.0                 minor.patch
138641             2020-07-08          0.4.0                 minor
138641             2020-07-11          0.5.0                 minor
138641             2020-07-12          0.6.0                 minor
```

I am trying to compare the versions between consecutive rows and then label them, but the problem I am facing is often the first `commit_date` of some of the `api_spec_id` have a label as well, as we can see for the id 138641, when it should be empty as there is no previous row to compare to.

This is the code below, I feel the issue is probably coming because of the `sem` function because it extracts the version for all the rows, which could be causing some issues in the `diff`, but then again it works for some of the `id`'s which is strange, and I am not able to debug this issue.

```
pat = r'(?P<major>\d+)\.(?P<minor>\d+)\.(?P<patch>\d+)(?:\.(?P<micro>\d+))?'

sem = new['info_version'].str.extract(pat).fillna(0).astype(int)

diff = sem.diff().fillna(0).ne(0)

new['label'] = diff.dot(sem.columns + '.').str.rstrip('.')
```

The second part of the code is for all versions which are not valid semantic versions and have to be parsed with the `Version` class.

```
attrs = ['major', 'minor', 'micro', 'pre', 'post', 'dev', 'local']
def extract_version(ver):
    ver = Version(ver)  
    return pd.Series({attr: getattr(ver, attr) for attr in attrs}, dtype=str)


sem = new['info_version'].agg(extract_version).fillna('').rename(columns={'micro': 'patch'})
diff = sem.ne(sem.shift().fillna(sem.iloc[0]))
new['label'] = diff.dot(sem.columns + '.').str.rstrip('.')
```

Is there any other way I could calculate the difference? Any suggestions or ideas would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of your previous questions, I recommend you to group by `api_spec_id` column to process versions:

```
api_spec_id       commit_date   info_version    label
500                2021-02-01            1.1     
138641             2020-06-25          0.1.0    major  # <- without groupby
```

If you use `groupby`, the output will be:

```
api_spec_id       commit_date   info_version    label
500                2021-02-01            1.1     
138641             2020-06-25          0.1.0           # <- with groupby
```

So you should use:

```
pat = r'(?P<major>\d+)\.(?P<minor>\d+)\.(?P<patch>\d+)(?:\.(?P<micro>\d+))?'

sem = new['info_version'].str.extract(pat).fillna(0).astype(int)

# diff = sem.diff().fillna(0).ne(0)
diff = sem.groupby(new['api_spec_id']).diff().fillna(0).ne(0)

new['label'] = diff.dot(sem.columns + '.').str.rstrip('.')
```

For your second part of code, it's exactly the same problem:

```
attrs = ['major', 'minor', 'micro', 'pre', 'post', 'dev', 'local']
def extract_version(ver):
    ver = Version(ver)  
    return pd.Series({attr: getattr(ver, attr) for attr in attrs}, dtype=str)


sem = new['info_version'].agg(extract_version).fillna('').rename(columns={'micro': 'patch'})
# diff = sem.ne(sem.shift().fillna(sem.iloc[0]))
diff = (sem.groupby(new['api_spec_id'], group_keys=False)
           .apply(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift().fillna(x.iloc[0]))))

new['label'] = diff.dot(sem.columns + '.').str.rstrip('.')
```

In both cases, the output is now:

```
>>> new
    api_spec_id commit_date info_version        label
0           500  2020-07-22          1.1             
1           500  2020-11-09          1.1             
2           500  2020-11-16          1.1             
3           500  2020-11-16          1.1             
4           500  2020-11-23          1.1             
5           500  2021-02-01          1.1             
6        138641  2020-06-25        0.1.0             
7        138641  2020-06-25        0.1.0             
8        138641  2020-06-27        0.1.0             
9        138641  2020-06-27        0.1.9        patch
10       138641  2020-06-27       0.1.10        patch
11       138641  2020-06-27       0.1.11        patch
12       138641  2020-06-27       0.1.13        patch
13       138641  2020-06-27       0.1.14        patch
14       138641  2020-06-27       0.1.15        patch
15       138641  2020-06-28        0.2.0  minor.patch
16       138641  2020-06-30        0.2.1        patch
17       138641  2020-07-01        0.3.0  minor.patch
18       138641  2020-07-08        0.4.0        minor
19       138641  2020-07-11        0.5.0        minor
20       138641  2020-07-12        0.6.0        minor
```